# Flutter: Unable to pass onSubmitted in TextField

Tags: flutter, textfield

I'm making custom TextField in Flutter.

I need to pass onSubmitted.

However when I try to print the value, nothing changes.
But when I try to print directly in this widget it prints successfully.

```dart
class SearchTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  const SearchTextField({
    required this.hintText,
    required this.onSubmitted,
    super.key,
  });

  final String hintText;
  final void Function(String value) onSubmitted;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final isDark = context.isDarkTheme;
    return Container(
      height: 48,
      width: double.infinity,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      decoration: ShapeDecoration(
        color: isDark ? AppColors.cardBgDark : AppColors.cardBg,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        ),
      ),
      child: TextField(
        onSubmitted: onSubmitted,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
        style: AppFonts.body15R.copyWith(
          color: isDark ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
        ),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          filled: true,
          fillColor: isDark ? AppColors.helpCardBgDark : AppColors.cardBg,
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: 14,
            horizontal: 16,
          ),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
          ),
          prefixIcon: Image.asset(AppImages.search),
          hintText: hintText,
          hintStyle: const TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFFACACAC),
            fontSize: 15,
            fontFamily: 'SF Pro Text',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            height: 1.33,
            letterSpacing: -0.24,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
SearchTextField(
                hintText: 'Title',
                onSubmitted: (searchText) {
                 // nothing happens here
                   print(searchText);
                },
              ),
```

What I've tried:

1. Convert to StatefullWidget
2. Add onChanged, onEditingComplete
3. Convert to TextFormField
4. Change textInputAction

**UPD:**
Guys, I know how ridiculous it is.
After 5 hours in a raw I finally found a solution.
I tested it on the wrong screen.
Anyway thanks everyone for your help. I hope at least you'll laugh.

Comment: I think you have it wrong: You did you mean  to assign a `TextEditingController`?

Comment: I just did, but this does not help

Comment: I tried different variations like just assigning TextEditingController, using it inside onSubmit, using it inside onEditingComplete. All the same

Comment: I checked your code, it works fine. can you put some screenshots or a video?

Comment: @Hamed I know it should work. It even work once. But only once. It may be some kind of bug. But I can't find out at least workaround

Comment: I am not saying it should work, it is working I test it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code widget and it works well.

Keep it as a stateless widget, maybe it print but you don't see the value because the console show many messages.

[image]

Comment: My console is clean. The action on submit is not triggered at all.
I may be some system bug, 'cause once it worked fine. But only once.